# Defining similar space to $L^p$ for function of random variables

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

We know that $L^p = \{X \mid \mathbb{E}[|X|^p] < \infty\}$ spaces are vector spaces.
Let $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. I would like to define a similar space with respect to function $g$. In particular, I want something like $L_g = \{X \mid \mathbb{E}[g(X)] < \infty \}$ that makes sure $g(X)$ is integrable. However, in this definition, $L_g$ is not a vector space. Any ideas how it is possible to define such a space to assure it is a vector space?

Comment: You'd need to impose some conditions on $g$ if you want a vector space.  For a related notion (though one that is not always a vector space), you can read about [Birnbaum-Orlicz spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birnbaum%E2%80%93Orlicz_space).

Comment: @Nate Thanks for your comment. I have some conditions on $g$. For example, $g$ is positive, convex and coercive (i.e. $g(y) \to \infty as |y| \to \infty$) and I want the definition to somehow generalize $L^p$. In particular, I would like it holds for $g(y) = y^2$ and $g(y) = |y|$.

Comment: This is sounding very similar to the Birnbaum-Orlicz spaces I mentioned above.  Have you had a chance to read about them yet?

Comment: @ Nate Eldredge Thanks for your comment. I read about them and I think that's exactly what I wanted.